# Filter SPARQL using Jena

Tags: filter, sparql, jena, semantic-web

I have quiz game in which user have to answer questions like:
What is German capital city name? Options are:
Berlin
Madrid
London
The data are in my owl file. I have another ontology also in which I have rdfs:comment of resources (options of quiz questions) like rdfs:comment of Berlin, London etc. 
I want if user choose the wrong option i-e London, rdfs:comment of right option should be displayed to user, Berlin in this case.

The right (correct) option I have is in java variable 'correct' and if user click wrong option, I want to show the rdfs:comment of correct option as:

```
 "SELECT  * " +
            " WHERE {   ?x rdfs:comment ?y   "  +  "FILTER regex( ?y ,'"+correct+"' ) " +

      "}";
```

But it does not give me the rdfs:comment of correct option when user clicked on wrong option. 
Is there any problem in the query?

Comment: Please print the query `System.out` and show the query here. And what is the value of the Java object with the variable `correct`?

Comment: correct value changes when user goes from one question to another. What is capital of Germany, correct is Berlin. In another question What is capital of Italy, correct value is Rome, and so on. The quiz is java swings and user click NEXT to go to next question.

Comment: @AKSW, it shows null value for correct variable in print out, I dont know why. SELECT  *  WHERE {   ?x rdfs:comment ?y   FILTER regex( ?x ,'null' ) }

Comment: But then you know the answer. This is an issue in your Java application, obviously the value of `correct` is NULL, i.e. not assigned at the point where you print the query.

Comment: Any solution to this? @AKSW

Comment: @s.shah we can't answer this, since you haven't shown the Java code that actually creates/initializes the variable `correct`.

Comment: Right, what shall we do?! There is only one generic answer, make sure that in your code the variable `correct` is set BEFORE you use the query - but this should be quite obvious. That's all Java basics and not a SPARQL problem.

Comment: public String correct;                                                                                                    one = Question.get(0).getChoiceOne(); //one is variable                          two = Question.get(0).getChoiceTwo(); //two variable                           correct = Question.get(0).getCorrectChoice() ; //correct is variable and have the correct answer

Comment: After query I use this code:  Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
 QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model) ;
 ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect() ;
        while (results.hasNext())
 {
  QuerySolution binding = results.nextSolution();

                Literal l=binding.getLiteral("y");
                String s=l.toString();
              
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Answer is"+l);

Comment: And one other thing, the correct value now contains the right options like: Berlin, Rome etc when I print out the query. I wonder still it does not give me the rdfs:comment of filtered resource.